# Errors in a React.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on integrating maps in my react project. I am getting some errors. I used typescript in my project.

Below is a code which shows error:

```
handleChange = (e:any) => {
 this.setState({location: this.state.location})
     function initAutocomplete() {
       var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
       var searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
       searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
         this.setState({ PlaceName: document.getElementById('pac-input').value });
       });
     }
   
     initAutocomplete();
 
 }
```

This are errors which I am facing:

1.This error is shown at line no.5 in var searchbox last bracket (input)

Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLInputElement'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.ts(2345)

2. This error is shown at line no.7 in this.setSatate

Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'SearchBox'.ts(2339)

3. This error is shown at line no.7 in document.getElementById('pac-input')

Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

4. This error is shown at line no.7 in last value

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)

Comment: this is not a react project you are working on, why do I say this? Because you are manually wiring up DOM elements with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is the most powerful, useful and wonderful thing *if* you know what you're doing and how to use it. If you don't it will be your worst nightmare.

This is why 3/4 of your errors are because you are using TS wrong with React.

Let me rewrite your code so it will work with TypeScript:

```html
handleChange = (e:any)/* #1 */ => {
    this.setState({location: this.state.location}) // #2
        function initAutocomplete() {
          const input = document.getElementById('pac-input')! as HTMLInputElement //#3 #4;
          const searchBox = new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
          searchBox.addListener('change', function() { // THERE IS NO SUCH THING "places_changed" as an event. ~ Would "change" help? ~
            this.setState({ PlaceName: document.getElementById('pac-input').value #5 });
          });
        }
      
        initAutocomplete();
    
}
```

#1 Why are you setting event to any? it is not efficient and if you don't use event inside your code - don't put it inside your code - it would be much more nicer to look and read.

#2 Why are you setting the state to it current value? it would reduce the performance of your code because you're trying to render it twice(!) with one function.

- There are two "setState" in one function instead of one. each of them re rendering the page.

#3 Why are you using var and not const or let? there are a lot of problems with using var, and since ES2015 const and let replaced var. You should consider not using it.

#4 when you want to assign an element from the DOM TS don't knows if it exits or not so it would return HTMLElement | null. But because you're writing the code you knows there is an Element so you add ! at the end .getElementById('myID')!.

- Now it return HTMLElement and not HTMLElement | null.

#5 You should declare Elements before you're using "setState".
like:

```html
const pacInput = document.getElementById('pac-input')! as HTMLInputElement
```

---

Now you should tell TS what the Element you are using if it a div, an input, a button etc... so you're writing the type of the element "as HTML(ELEMENT_TYPE_FROM_THE_LIST)";

So it should looks like:

```html
document.getElementById("myID")! as HTMLDivElement;

// Now TS knows the Element exist and a div Element
```

This code would fix 3 of your code errors.

Let me know about the setState error.

Extra:

If you want to run a function on the fly you should write it as:

```html
(function(){
  --DO SOME STUFF
})
```

Because it is a function on the fly, you don't need to declare nor call it. It will automatically executed even inside other functions.

I really recommend you to learn how to use TS with React. [This](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/) website has a lot of great sources!

BTW:

If you're using React, Why are you writing elements inside the HTML? This is what JSX for.

You should read more about React JSX [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Comment: Just a quick note about some of the phrasing in this post. I have edited it to make it beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems start with the fact that you are not working on a React project, in other words you are not writing your JavaScript as a React frontend but rather a plain JavaScript application.

What do I mean?

In the React view of things, your search bar would be a component, or in other words, your `input`, would be its own component called `SearchBar`, so instead of this:

```
const input = document.getElementById('pac-input')! as HTMLInputElement //#3 #4;
```

You would write a whole component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { term: '' };

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  };

  onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.onFormSubmit(this.state.term);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar ui segment">
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Some Input Field</label>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onInputChange} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Give that a try and if you run into trouble come back and ask a question.